# How to get the superset of all XML paths from an XML column in a table

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a table with an XML column. I have no data dictionary for the column or definition for the XML structure. There are about 1.5 million records. From visual inspection of a small sample, the structure of the XML appears to be fairly similar. What I'd like to be able to do is to run some SQL that will give me the superset of XML structure across all the records.

The table is called `Remittance` and the column is called `RemittInstr`.

For example, if I have two test data records whose XML value in the `RemittInstr`column is:

row 1:

```
<ri>
    <Msg Type="MT103">
        <AccountNo>12345678</AccountNo>
        <Description code="ORCSR">Ordering Customer<Description>
    </Msg>
</ri>
```

row 2:

```
<ri>
    <Msg Type="MT202">
        <BICFI>ABCD1234</BICFI>
        <Description code="FI">Financial Institution<Description>
    </Msg>
</ri>
```

How do I write a query that will return the following rows:

```
/ri
/ri/Msg
/ri/Msg/@Type
/ri/Msg/AccountNo
/ri/Msg/BICFI
/ri/Msg/Description
/ri/Msg/Description/@code
```

So that I can get a full picture of the structure of the XML across all the rows?

Edit: This is sufficiently different to the linked questions as the linked questions only deal with a single XML value. The question is about finding the structure of the XML across the rows in an entire table. The solution to doing this is sufficiently different. @Charlieface has provided a link to a good solution in his comments below.

Comment: T-SQL is a SQL dialect that is used by multiple products including Sybase, SQL Server, and Azure Synapse. What is the (R)DBMS product you are using here? [Edit] your question to tag that product, and (if relevant) the version tag for the product as well.

Comment: Sounds like generating this might take a while since you need to recursively parse each node in each row, are you sure this dictionary will help you and will not just be a lot of noise

Comment: @siggemannen - yes, but there's only one way to find out anyway. It would be a really useful generic tool.

Comment: @siggemannen - yes, I think that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you. I will adapt it for multiple rows and post it here.

Comment: This should work for you https://dbfiddle.uk/CJaUUsHZ see my linked answer above. Getting the attribute names complicates things a lot, you could have just done https://dbfiddle.uk/cm2nruki

Comment: @Charlieface - this works really well. I'd written a solution, but it involved the creation of a table-valued function. My knowledge of the XML related functions is a little limited. Have adopted your solution, but added an simpler earlier CTE to limit the number of rows from the source down to a manageable sample. If they re-open the question, feel free to post your solution and I will mark as answer. Many thanks.

Comment: @Charlieface that's a very nice solution, i think this question can be reopened, because the dups don't handle attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE for this. I would warn you that this is likely to be very slow on 1.5m rows.

It's a bit complicated to get attribute names, because it doesn't seem you can do `.nodes('@*')` to get all attributes.

Instead you need to `CROSS APPLY` a union of the node name and its atttributes.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      xpath = r.RemittanceInstr.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)'),
      child = r.RemittanceInstr
    FROM Remittance r

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      xpath = CONCAT(cte.xpath, '/', v2.name),
      v2.child
    FROM cte
    CROSS APPLY cte.child.nodes('*') x(nd)
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (x.nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') )) v(name)
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
          v.name,
          x.nd.query('*')

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
          CONCAT(v.name, '/@', x2.attr.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)')),
          NULL
        FROM x.nd.nodes('@*') x2(attr)
    ) v2(name, child)
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  xpath
FROM cte;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/G_PEIjYw)